# Pass C# code using mvc razor view engine to angular page

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, windows

I have this below c# code which gets me the username.Now, i want to pass this username details to the frontend for display. I am using mvc with razor view engine and front end is using angularjs
how can i pass this C# to html page. ? any idea ?

```
String UserName = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
```

Can someone please share an example.

Comment: <% %> ---- is this a way to pass it ?

Comment: @Wai Ha Lee- could you please check my question again. i have modified it. if you could remove the hold on this question. ?

Comment: @gunr2171- could you please check my question again. i have modified it. if you could remove the hold on this question. ?

Comment: @cimmanon- could you please check my question again. i have modified it. if you could remove the hold on this question. ?

Comment: @ketan- could you please check my question again. i have modified it. if you could remove the hold on this question. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use that data binding syntax to bind a property from the object you are passing in to the web form. But that's if you are using webforms. If you are using Mvc with razor view engine, the binding syntax is different. However, as you tagged your question using Angular too, if you are using that, you might want to just return your data from your C# controller in a json format and bind that to the Html view using Angular data binding. You can get more help by giving some more details about your app.

Comment: @artist_dev- modified my question. yes, its using mvc with razor view engine and front end is using angular

Comment: Then you can use something like @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.UserName) in your cshtml file, where m represents your ViewModel defined in your controller, and declared in the razor cshtml file that represents your View something like this: @model MyViewModel. UserName is a field or property on your viewModel.